# PyTorch print output to 2dp

Tags: python, printing, decimal, pytorch

Is there a way to print the output of a CNN model evaluation to 2dp given that the output is a multi element FloatTensor?

eg.

```
prediction = torch.exp(model(image2))
print(prediction)
```

Out:

```
Variable containing:
 2.84e-01  1.68e-07  7.16e-01
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x3]
```

It would be better if I could output the value as:

```
Variable containing:
 0.28  0.00  0.72
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x3]
```

I've tried:

```
print("%.2f" % prediction)
```

and using:

```
torch.set_printoptions(precision=2)
```

But neither give the desired effect.

I had a look on the documentation page:

http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#creation-ops

...under 'torch.set_printoptions' but I can't see how any of the arguments might help in this situation.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not think that you can convert from the scientific notation as of now. There is a [Github issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6865) that aims to fix this in future.

Comment: Okay, thanks for finding that post

Answer (score 5):

This has now been implemented. Use

```
torch.set_printoptions(sci_mode=False)
```

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.set_printoptions